# Bootstrap carousel stops cycling when scrolling the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is the home page of my blog http://www.lowcoupling.com
it is a tumblr blog based on twitter bootstrap and its carousel
I can't see why if I scroll the page don and then up back again the carousel stops cycling.

Thanks

Comment: Seems to work for me on Chrome. What browser are you using? Also, how are you scrolling the page? Mouse, mouse wheel, keyboard, touch, etc.

Comment: before to ask I tried on chrome and safari on a macbook pro i7 with lion installed. But I guessed it could be just a problem of my own configuration. I am deleting this question in the afternoon in case of no answers. thanks